# Count with CSS Animation: Animate only once instead of continuously

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Assumed we have this simple piece of CSS animated counter:

```css
div::after {
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  content: counter(count);
  animation: counter 5s linear infinite;
  counter-reset: count 0;
}

@keyframes counter {
  0% {
    counter-increment: count 0;
  }
  10% {
    counter-increment: count 8;
  }
  20% {
    counter-increment: count 16;
  }
  30% {
    counter-increment: count 32;
  }
  40% {
    counter-increment: count 64;
  }
  50% {
    counter-increment: count 128;
  }
  60% {
    counter-increment: count 256;
  }
  70% {
    counter-increment: count 512;
  }
  80% {
    counter-increment: count 1024;
  }
  90% {
    counter-increment: count 2048;
  }
  100% {
    counter-increment: count 4000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

As you can see, the counter begins counting again from zero when reaching its final value (4000).

**How can I set the counter to count only once and remain at its final value (without counting again)?**

Comment: If i may, why you using counter instead of simply modifying the content property ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `infinite` to `forwards` ....

> [`forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)
>
> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count:

```css
div::after {
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  content: counter(count);
  animation: counter 5s linear forwards;
  counter-reset: count 0;
}

@keyframes counter {
  0% {
    counter-increment: count 0;
  }
  10% {
    counter-increment: count 8;
  }
  20% {
    counter-increment: count 16;
  }
  30% {
    counter-increment: count 32;
  }
  40% {
    counter-increment: count 64;
  }
  50% {
    counter-increment: count 128;
  }
  60% {
    counter-increment: count 256;
  }
  70% {
    counter-increment: count 512;
  }
  80% {
    counter-increment: count 1024;
  }
  90% {
    counter-increment: count 2048;
  }
  100% {
    counter-increment: count 4000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```